# Kendo Angular 2 Grid no longer supports column titles after latest update

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

After updating to version 0.13.2, the Kendo Angular 2 Grid no longer sets column titles according to the `title` attribute. Even setting the title for all columns to `title="test"`, without binding it to anything, does not trigger any changes; the column header text always defaults to the field name.